# Show Skyrim vs. CoD:MW3 ads on relevant questions for new users

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, advertisements

The SE team put a lot of effort into the [Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim vs. Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/) promotion, I think it could be effective to try and use it to retain more users that get to our site by searching for specific questions.

We get a lot of hits on many questions for new high-profile releases in the first few days. Making them aware that they have the chance to win some very nice prizes by participating in this site might get more people to try it out and contribute questions and answers.

To make those users aware of the promotion we could display an in-house advert for the promotion

- on every question tagged Skyrim or CoD:MW3
- only for new users without accounts

My idea is that this could [help improve our conversion rate](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/why-is-our-conversion-rate-so-low), to get users to stay after they got their question answered and to entice them to try out this site and give it a chance.

Comment: I've already seen adverts in the sidebar for the minisite

Comment: @Thomas I've now also seen it, but my main point is that it shouldn't be random, it should be shown to new users for the skyrim or MW3 tag at least once, not relying on chance. The ad also doesn't mention the chance of getting a prize, the ad is probably pretty confusing if you don't know what it's about.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I was just mentioning that I've already noticed advertising for it. Personally, I hardly look at the sidebar anyway, a banner ad would bring much more attention.

Answer (score 8):

Besides 100% agreeing, I think it will be worthwhile to dedicate some thought to how the ad  should look like. If I were to visit a random site for a question I have I'll surely ignore any ad shouting "you have a chance to win PS3!".

I'm not really sure how a good ad *could* be designed, though. Maybe something like a live ticker displaying

> Since this is a Skyrim question, anyone answering it correctly has a good chance to win a PS3 or XBOX360 in 4 days and 23 hours, even if they are not registered users! [learn more](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/)

And make "Skyrim" some image, not just text, to emphasize this isn't automatically-generated for *every* tag.

Likewise, something like

> Every Skyrim or Modern-Warfare-3 question you ask in the coming 4 days and 23 hours makes you eligible to actually win something, besides getting a good answer, even if you're not registered! [learn more](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/)

for the main site.

Comment: The [banner from the blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/11/elder-scrolls-v-vs-modern-warfare-3/#more-2935) could serve as a base background. I agree that we should try to avoid looking somehow shady.